# Is it good to use user-input as partition key value in DynamoDB

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I have a partition key called pkey
Is it good to have something like `PRODUCT#GLS10` where `GLS10` is the product skuCode (which is user input) as the sort key?
Or, is it best practice to use UUID like `PRODUCT#a8b8f5ca-9faf-44f8-b3a0-4faff82a282d`?

Since skuCode is unique, I think it's gonna be alright or am I wrong?
P.S. I use adjacency list pattern for schema design

Comment: what is the scale?

Comment: @bestwishes It's just like ecommerce platform like Amazon etc.. Could you elaborate more about what it has to do with scale?